# Filter Limit in opencart

Tags: php, filter, opencart

I have 266 filters in 1 group in opencart. Then I am trying to add the 267th and I get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: filter_description in /home/eshop/public_html/admin/controller/catalog/filter.php on
line 386 

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
/home/eshop/public_html/admin/controller/catalog/filter.php on
line 386

Notice: Undefined index: sort_order in
/home/eshop/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-admin_model_catalog_filter.php
on line 48

Notice: Undefined index: filter_description in
/home/eshop/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-admin_model_catalog_filter.php
on line 53

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
/home/eshop/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-admin_model_catalog_filter.php
on line 53

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already
sent by (output started at
/home/eshop/public_html/admin/index.php:85) in
/home/eshop/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php
on line 28

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already
sent by (output started at
/home/eshop/public_html/admin/index.php:85) in
/home/eshop/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php
on line 29
```

Is there a limit in the number of filters in a group?
My Oc version is 1.5.6.4

Comment: You should post the source code.

Comment: It's opencart core code. No customization.

Comment: It's OpenCart source code yes, but based on those errors you are using a VQmod that is modifying the standard code, hence the `vq2-` files

Comment: But why in the 267th filter and above... I ll check this too.